# Apache tomcat not deploying in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat

my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TTV2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My html file is `tictt.html` when i tried running it in apache tomcat server 9. it gives a 404 error `resource not found`. i tried doing the solutions without any avail.

```
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TTV2' did not find a matching property.
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 4 2016 18:22:47 UTC
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\NNK\NewTicTacToe\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\NNK\NewTicTacToe\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\NNK\NewTicTacToe\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\endorsed
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102;C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse;;.
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1433 ms
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
Jul 25, 2016 12:31:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 672 ms
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that too didn't work

Comment: you file `tictt.html` is part of the application you have built? if this is the landing page why isn't this defined in the `web.xml` file?

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan yes its  part of the project. but  i tried to directly run the html file

Comment: how do you do that? did u right click the file and select Run As -> Run on Server?

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan yes

Comment: While you can run a file / app this way, I would strongly suggest you to build the complete app and place the app in the `webapps` directory and then start your server. Once the server successfully starts up, try to access the app by using the browser firing the URL by providing the context root and the path to the file.

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan how shoould i place in the root.can you give an example